# Appcelerator Background Job

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

We are developing an app(iOS) in appcelerator which  has a sync contact feature in it. This calls an API which syncs contacts with server. I want this to run in background of the app. It should not make the user stop on a screen. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the iOS background it's only when the app goes to the background and has limitation set by the OS - so if, for example it takes too long to process, or if the OS needs memory - it will shut it down.

I'm guessing (correct me if I'm wrong) that you want to do the sync while the app is running, yet not compromise the user experience by freezing the app?

First of, know the the request to the server is made async - only processing the response is made on the js thread - so to make better use of your single thread I suggest you view the following presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/ronaldtreur/titanium-making-the-most-of-your-single-thread

If you truly want a **background thread** to do the job, currently you would have to write your own native module to do that.

Also, this is something to look forward to in future versions: https://github.com/appcelerator/cspec-titanium-multithreading

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [background service](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService) for that.

But be aware, that this services will stop after a few minutes